# Typescript returns some functions as self?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i looking for a way to create a function that's create 2 other functions as self function.

```
var anyVariable = createMeFunc();

public createMeFunc(): string {       

   var setFunc = ( value: any) => {
      console.log("set function");
   }
   var getFunc = (): string => {
      console.log("get function");
      return "returnVal";
   }
   return setFunc, getFunc;
}

anyVariable("someValue"); //calls setFunc
anyVariable(); //calls getFunc, returns "returnVal"
```

This is just a example if something is unclear i'm happy for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-ES5 solution could look like this:

```
interface Foo {
    (): any;
    (value: any): void;
}

function createFoo(): Foo {
    var getFunc = () => { console.log("get"); return "foo"; }
    var setFunc = (value: any) => { console.log("set"); }

    return (value?: any) => {
        if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            setFunc(value);
        } else {
            return getFunc();
        }
    }
}

var f = createFoo();
f("bar");
f();
```

Comment: public createFoo(): { (value?): any; } this should be valid, too ? But the compiler do not show any error by setting f("", ""). Do the compiler shows you any intellisense ?

Comment: @Abc That bit of code makes no sense to me - could you try and explain what you are trying to do? -- `f("","")` is supposed to result in a compiler warning because the number of arguments does not match any of the signatures of f.

Comment: You should use if(typeof value==='undefined') really, because false or 0 could be valid values passed into the setter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for EcmaScript 5 setters and getters:

```
var foo = new Foo();

class Foo{  
    get anyVariable():string{
      console.log("get function");
      return "returnVal";
    }
    set anyVariable(string){
        console.log("set function");
    }
}

foo.anyVariable="someValue"; //calls setFunc
var x = foo.anyVariable; //calls getFunc, returns "returnVal"
```

[See it in typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20foo%20=%20new%20Foo%28%29;%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%7B%09%0A%09get%20anyVariable%28%29%3astring%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28%22get%20function%22%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22returnVal%22;%0A%09%7D%0A%09set%20anyVariable%28string%29%7B%0A%09%09console.log%28%22set%20function%22%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afoo.anyVariable=%22someValue%22;%20//calls%20setFunc%0Avar%20x%20=%20foo.anyVariable;%20//calls%20getFunc,%20returns%20%22returnVal%22)